# sum of TOP N in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Below is my sample table. I want to get the TOP1 student for sum of score of each course

```
    create table SC(
SId varchar(10) comment "Student ID",
CId varchar(10) comment "Course ID",
score decimal(18,1) comment "Test Score");

insert into SC values('01' , '01' , 100);
insert into SC values('01' , '01' , 80);
insert into SC values('01' , '02' , 90);
insert into SC values('01' , '03' , 99);
insert into SC values('02' , '01' , 70);
insert into SC values('02' , '02' , 60);
insert into SC values('02' , '03' , 60);
insert into SC values('02' , '03' , 70);
```

so the result would be:

[image]

I used below code but the score was not sum

```
SELECT SId,CId,sum(score)  from sc a
where 1 > (SELECT count(*) from sc where a.CId=CId and  a.score <score)
group by CId
ORDER BY CId
```

I have Mysql 5.7, can you plz help?

Comment: Does this throw an error? I'd think `a` would be not be available in subquery.

Comment: Seriously consider storing integers using an integer datatype

Comment: it shows student 01's highest score for each course instead of sum scores

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SId,
       CId,
       SUM(score) score
FROM SC a
GROUP BY SId, CId
HAVING score >= ALL ( SELECT SUM(score)
                      FROM SC b
                      WHERE a.CId=b.CId
                      GROUP BY b.SId, b.CId );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b0f06b06c5446a61600570f9ff89b0c5)

> what if there are more students and I want TOP3 for example?

```
SELECT SId, CId, score
FROM ( SELECT SId, CId, score,
              @rownumber := IF(@course = CId, @rownumber + 1, 1) rownumber,
              @course := CId
       FROM ( SELECT SId, CId, SUM(score) score
              FROM SC a
              GROUP BY SId, CId ) data, 
            ( SELECT @rownumber:=0, @course:='' ) vars
       ORDER BY CId, score DESC ) data
WHERE rownumber <= 3;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1ea54ed0a1fad9506e1c03bb08bde5e9)

Comment: it works thx! what if there are more students and I want TOP3 for example?

Comment: @RRRosa Oh, this another task is more hard. You must to enumerate summarised records (emulate ROW_NUMBER using user-defined variables) and select the records where this number is not more than 3.

Comment: /me did not know about `HAVING ALL`.... so, i was doing: [dbfidle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=362a85b3f6d098b31cf3ba896aeaa3ca)

Comment: @Luuk, same question about display TOP3 if more students? I still cannot figure it out

Comment: @RRRosa Variant for TOP 3 added (the source data is expanded).

Comment: This script (unfortunately!) produces warnings as `Warning | 1287 | Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'.`, so be warned..... (i was doing this in MySQL 8.0.18)

Comment: @Luuk Please look at the version number which is used by OP. For version 8+ the solution would be completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Use following query for the desired output.

```
SELECT `SId`,`CId`,sum(`score`) from sc
GROUP BY `SID`,`CId`
ORDER BY `SId` ASC, `CId` ASC;
```

Comment: Solves another task. Result does not match to provided. Citate: *I want to get the **TOP1** student for sum of score of each course* - whereas the answer gets all sums.